# JQuery return find in conjunction with eq

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to list the table cells in a specific header.

I pass in a table and then I used a passed in index to determine the header, this part is fine. The problem is when I try to get the cells from here then it's not working.

```
var $tableCells = $table.eq(index).find('td')
```

If I get the cells before I narrow down the headers then it works fine:

```
var $tableCells = $table.find('td')
```

It's most likely something simple but I'm new to JQuery.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Youve not told us what `$table` represents

Comment: Table just represents a html table. The one I refer to as being passed in.

Comment: So whats `$table.eq(i)` supposed to do - there is only 1 table by your description. So the only valid value of `i` would be zero, which makes no sense. Are you trying to get a specific column? You mention "headers" are you trying to get a specific `thead` column? Its not clear what you're trying ot do

Comment: I see, it's s'posed to get the column that's passed in through the index.

Comment: @Dane, do you maybe want to target specific row of table? Then using of eq have sense...Please provide HTML and desired output, it will be easier...

Comment: Do you want all `td`'s in a specific column defined by `index`?

Comment: Ditto. What does the HTML look like, and what do you want `$tableCells` to contain?

Comment: Yes you're right. I want to select a column using my index and then pull out all the td's.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're after the [`:nth-child` selector](https://api.jquery.com/nth-child-selector/). It can be used like the below to get the n'th `td` in each row of a table.

Note: the index passed to that selector, unlike most of javascript, is 1-based. so `nth-child(1)` will get the first child.

```js
var $table = $('table');
var index = 1;

var $tableCells = $table.find('tr td:nth-child(' + index + ')');
$tableCells.each(function(){
   alert($(this).html()); // alerts "row0 cell0" then "row1 cell0"
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>row0 cell0</td>
    <td>row0 cell1</td>
    <td>row0 cell2</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>row1 cell0</td>
    <td>row1 cell1</td>
    <td>row1 cell2</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, works a charm! Like I said I'm new to JQuery so thanks for your patience.

Comment: You're welcome, half the battle is always trying to work out what you're trying to do - answering is usually easy at that point :)